# Rotating lists in linear time and constant space (Java)

Tags: java

([The next iteration.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177414/rotating-lists-in-linear-time-and-constant-space-java-follow-up))

I have this small utility method for rotating `java.util.List`s in linear time, constant space:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import static java.util.Collections.swap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class contains a static method for rotating lists in linear time and
 * constant space.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Oct 6, 2017)
 */
public final class ListReversal {

    private ListReversal() {}

    /**
     * Performs the list rotation.
     * 
     * @param <T>           the list element type.
     * @param list          the list whose content to rotate.
     * @param rotationCount the number of steps to rotate to the right. If
     *                      negative, rotates to the left.
     */
    public static <T> void rotate(List<T> list, int rotationCount) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(list, "The input list is null.");

        if (rotationCount < 0) {
            rotateLeft(list, -rotationCount);
        } else if (rotationCount > 0) {
            rotateRight(list, rotationCount);
        }
    }

    private static <T> void rotateLeft(List<T> list, int rotationCount) {
        Collections.<T>reverse(list);
        rotationCount %= list.size();
        reverse(list, list.size() - rotationCount, list.size());
        reverse(list, 0, list.size() - rotationCount);
    }

    private static <T> void rotateRight(List<T> list, int rotationCount) {
        Collections.<T>reverse(list);
        rotationCount %= list.size();
        reverse(list, 0, rotationCount);
        reverse(list, rotationCount, list.size());
    }

    private static <T> void reverse(List<T> list, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        for (int i = fromIndex, j = toIndex - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
            swap(list, i, j);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        System.out.println(list);

        while (true) {
            int rotationCount = scanner.nextInt();
            rotate(list, rotationCount);
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to hear any comments regarding the above.

Comment: You can take a look at `Collections#rotate` for a more efficient implementation (your current algorithm is inefficient for `RandomAccess` lists, your `reverse` implementation is inefficient for lists without random access). You need only `rotateLeft` or `rotateRight` as a left rotate by `n` is equivalent to a right rotate by `size()-n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The time complexity of the `rotate` method is `O(N^2)` if the list doesn't support random access because each call to `swap` takes `O(N)` time. One can fix it by using two `ListIterators` (one going forward and one going backwards) to reverse a part of the list.
2. There's no need to create separate `rotateLeft` and `rotateRight` methods. You can always take the shift modulo the size of the list (in mathematical sense, without negative results, not in a sense of the operator `%`) instead.