# Rotating lists in linear time and constant space (Java) - follow-up

Tags: java, linked-list

([The previous and the initial iteration.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177326/rotating-lists-in-linear-time-and-constant-space-java))

After some critique, I found the way to keep the rotation operation also for `java.util.List`s that do not provide random access iterators:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class contains a static method for rotating lists in linear time and
 * constant space.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Oct 6, 2017)
 */
public final class ListRotation {

    private ListRotation() {}

    /**
     * Performs the list rotation.
     *
     * @param <T> the list element type.
     * @param list the list whose content to rotate.
     * @param rotationCount the number of steps to rotate to the right. If
     * negative, rotates to the left.
     */
    public static <T> void rotate(List<T> list, int rotationCount) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(list, "The input list is null.");
        rotationCount %= list.size();

        if (rotationCount < 0) {
            rotationCount += list.size();
        }

        Collections.<T>reverse(list);
        Collections.<T>reverse(list.subList(0, rotationCount));
        Collections.<T>reverse(list.subList(rotationCount, list.size()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = 
                new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));

        System.out.println(list);

        while (true) {
            int rotationCount = scanner.nextInt();
            rotate(list, rotationCount);
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
}
```

So how does that look now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Input validation

If the list is empty, there will be division by zero.
Since you check for `null` input list,
it would make sense to do likewise for empty list as well.

#### Type parameter

The `<T>` is not needed in the `Collections.<T>reverse` statements,
this works just fine:

```
Collections.reverse(list);
Collections.reverse(list.subList(0, rotationCount));
Collections.reverse(list.subList(rotationCount, list.size()));
```